# regex print file extensions within strings perfectly

Tags: regex

I want a regex to get file extensions with 5 char prefix of it.

suppose Input :

> rtdsa.log;dsfdskj.env   uopy.java asdflhlahd   sdi.logasd   sdf.env98

I want:

> rtdsa.log    fdskj.env   uopy.java

rules:
print with 5 char prefix of extension, don't print if extension is continued by letter or number like .logasd or .log78

I tried:

```
'file ext': r'.(.log|.env|.java)[a-zA-Z0-9=:_\+\/-]{0}',
```

I got:

> > file ext   ->  d    file ext   ->  s    file ext   ->  a.log    file ext   ->  ;    file ext   ->  k    file ext   ->  j.env    file ext   ->  g
> > file ext  ->  p    file ext   ->  y.java    file ext  ->  i.log    file
> > ext   ->  a    file ext   ->  f.env    file ext   ->  9    file ext   ->  8
> > file ext  ->  b    file ext   ->  f.java    file ext  ->       file ext   ->  f
> > file ext  ->  l    file ext   ->  h`

Comment: Try `[^\s.]{1,5}\.(?:log|env|java)\b` or `\w{1,5}\.(?:log|env|java)\b`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/o16qJY/1).

Comment: How does `uopy.java` match the 5 characters rule?

Comment: hey @WiktorStribiżew  It's working perfectly. thanks for the solution. I have doubt regards, how to regex a defined filename.ext like composer.json ?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε {1,5} will be considered after identifying  .ext and blindly print 5 char prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\w{1,5}\.(?:log|env|java)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o16qJY/1). Note that you may replace `\w` with `\S` to match any non-whitespace chars.

**Details**

- `\w{1,5}` - one to five letters/digits/underscores
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?:log|env|java)` - `log`, `env` or `java` substrings
- `\b`  - a word boundary, immediately to the right, there must be a non-word char or end of string.